# How do I close the keyboard in textfield without clearing it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently using unfocus() to close the keyboard. However, when I close it in this way, the text I was typing is deleted. I have also tried the following methods.

```
・FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());

・_focusNode.unfocus();

・SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
```

However, none of them work as I want them to (i.e., the input information is retained even after closing the keyboard).
I'm hoping for a similar behavior to `TextInputAction.done`.
Please teach me how to do this.

Comment: can you provide the code of your Form and / or TextFormField please ?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but I think it's because I'm using statenotifierprovider with statelesswidget. I'm really sorry to all the people who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please define TextEditingController outside the Build method.

```
class YourClass extends StatelessWidget {

  TextEditingController txtCntSearch = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(controller: txtCntSearch);
  }
}
```

Hope this will works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I've already done it and this is what I see.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but I think it's because I'm using statenotifierprovider with statelesswidget. I'm really sorry to all the people who answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this it will work..

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it disappears, just like the example above.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but I think it's because I'm using statenotifierprovider with statelesswidget. I'm really sorry to all the people who answered.